# Search nested lists in JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, search

I am trying to implement a simple search function where, if you type a town into a search box, it'll bring you up a telephone number for that area. The easiest way to store this data is to store the towns in a list within JSON. However:

```
var abc = {
  "partner": {
    "name": "North East & Cumbria (EDT)",
    "number": "01915008717",
    "areas": {
    "authority": ["Allerdale", "Barrow-in-Furness", "Carlisle"]
    }
  }
};


$.each(abc.partner.areas, function(key, val){
  if ((val.authority.search(new RegExp("Carlisle", "i")) != -1)) {
    // Action here
  }
});
```

This doesn't work for some reason. Am I on the right lines?

Comment: There's no keyless lists in there there. Am I missing something?

Comment: `val.authority` should be just `val`.  `key` will be `"authority"` and the `val` will be the array

Comment: Though really you do not need the each.  `if (abc.partner.area.authority.search( ... ) != -1)`

Comment: There'll be multiple "partner" objects in place, I forgot to mention this. The each is to iterate through those. Woops :-s

Comment: Given your json above, there cannot be multiple partner objects.

Comment: I'm aware the JSON would need to be adjusted to accommodate multiple partner objects. I only needed to include the one for the purpose of this query.

Comment: Nooooo, you need to show us an example of json that reflects the **actual** layout.  Giving us a different layout affects the answers you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi brother as per i understand your question i modified the code if you need any update or help comment me back

```
 var abc = {
  "partner": {
    "name": "North East & Cumbria (EDT)",
    "number": "01915008717",
    "areas": {
    "authority": ["Allerdale", "Barrow-in-Furness", "Carlisle"]
    }
  }
};


$.each(abc.partner.areas, function(key, val){
 console.log(val);
  if(jQuery.inArray("Carlisle", val)) {
    console.log(abc.partner.number);
}
});
```

Comment: That returns false positives, but making an adjustment to "if(jQuery.inArray("Carlisle", val) !== -1)" did the trick!